# Bazel working directory differs from Maven. How to migrate?

Tags: bazel

I have an existing project which is built with Maven. It typically defines several modules. I want to migrate this project to Bazel.

In a first attempt, I use

```
└── project
    ├── moduleA
    │   ├── BUILD
    │   ├── pom.xml
    │   └── src
    │       ├── main
    │       │   └── java
    │       └── test
    │           ├── data
    │           └── java
    ├── moduleB
    │   ├── BUILD
    │   ├── pom.xml
    │   └── src
    │       ├── main
    │       │   └── java
    │       └── test
    │           └── java
    ├── pom.xml
    └── WORKSPACE
```

It was not too hard to make the project build with Bazel. My problem is now that tests fails to find their test data.

Indeed, with Maven (or ant), the working directory is the one that contains the `pom.xml` (or `build.xml`). So, in that case for moduelA can do:

```
new File("src/test/data/foo.txt");
```

However, when the test runs in Bazel, the working directory is the sanboxed *runfiles* which are rooted like the workspace, i.e. the test must now open:

```
new File("projectA/src/test/data/foo.txt");
```

This is all fine after migration, but do you handle this situation *during* migration, i.e. how do you make the test pass both in Maven and in Bazel?

Is there any facility offered by the Bazel test runner to adapt the paths to legacy behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The current workaround I have is to check whether `new File(".").getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile()` is `__main__`.

See [TestFileUtil.java](https://github.com/jflex-de/jflex/pull/455)

Comment: I'm still looking for a better solution, because there would be many cases to consider with TestFileUtil to make it work properly.